# Question on the dynamics of the filled Julia set

Tags: dynamical-systems

Consider the complex map $z\rightarrow z^2+1$.  Find any one point that is

> a) not in the filled Julia set
>
> b) in the filled Julia set
>
> c) in the Julia set

I know that the Julia sets that are in the Mandelbrot set will be connected.  While the ones that are outside are disconnected.  But I don't know how to do this question please help ASAP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filled-in Julia set is defined as the set of all points with bounded orbit. So for (a), look at
$$
0 \to 1 \to 2 \to 5 \to 26 \to ...
$$
For (b), look at a root of $z^2+1=z.$ It is fixed under the map, so it has a bounded orbit.

Comment: Thank you so much Mr.Martin.  Can you explain the difference between b) and c)?

Comment: The Julia set is the boundary of the filled Julia set, which means that for any point from the Julia set and any $\epsilon>0$ there is a both a value from the filled Julia set and from outside the filled Julia set in the $\epsilon$-neighborhood of that point. Alas, I don't have a concrete example point for you at the moment.

Comment: is the border itself bounded then?

Comment: Yes, because the boundary of a bounded set is bounded, and it is not hard to show that the filled Julia set is contained in a circle of sufficient radius.